# CSS fit image to container

Tags: html, css, image

I am new to HTML and CSS and I am trying to learn as I develop on a project.
I am trying to make an image grid and when the mouse hovers the image an overlay text appears. The problem is that the image inside the container has some lateral gaps that I can't get remove: https://i.stack.imgur.com/weDkb.png

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<body>
    <h1>
        Art Page!
    </h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="container">
            <img src="images/owl.jpg" class="image">
            <div class="overlay">
              <div class="text">Example 1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="container">
            <img src="images/girl_freedom.jpg" class="image">
            <div class="overlay">
              <div class="text">Example 2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="container">
            <img src="images/soldiers.jpg" class="image">
            <div class="overlay">
              <div class="text">Example 3</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="container">
            <img src="images/brain.jpg" class="image">
            <div class="overlay">
              <div class="text">Example 4</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the css style sheet is:

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column {
  flex: auto;
}

.column img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  background-color: black;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Best regards

Comment: Suggestion : add a language identifier to highlight the css and make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you have to equalize the image size with the template using the code below

change this

```
.image {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

to this:

```
.image {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

demo in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ed93gpy/)

Or you have to put the image and the transparent layer inside a div and set `Position: Relative`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column {
  flex: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.column img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  background-color: black;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.img-container {
  display: inline-table;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Art Page!
</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="    https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" class="image">
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Example 1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="img-container">
           <img src="   https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" class="image">
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Example 1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="img-container">
           <img src="   https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" class="image">
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Example 1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="    https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" class="image">
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Example 1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```